# Is this possible to user two id in single column for make model relation in laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.7, has-many

The problem is, I have two different Ids of a Model that is being stored on a single column separated by a comma. like

> driver_id - 1,2,3

so there is any possibility to make any **Model Relation** using this Column. in my point of view, the answer is not. but can anyone do this? I just want to establish a **HasOne or HasMany Model Relation** from this column in **Laravel 5.7**.

I want to know that how can I make Model Relation with comma-separated id like **1,2,4**?

Please note that I do not want to use any **Get or Set** **Model Method** for this. it should work automatically by eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way in models

```
    public function getDriverAttribute($value)
    {
        $str = $value;
        $array = explode(",",$str));

        foreach($array as $key=>$value)
        {
            driver[] = Driver::find($value);
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you did not read my question.  I do not want to do this.  my question was, how to make hasMany relation if column have comma-separated value.